# Check if sybase table updated previously

Tags: sql, sybase

I am curious if there is a way to know if a sybase table has been updated /added previously? The table is generic, I am not allowed to use trigger or creating something like an updateDate field. Checking row count changes is not an option.

My first idea was to check the sysobjects table, but from what I see using the sql below, I don't think there is column storing any useful information for solving my case.

```
select name,userstat,uid, type, sysstat, indexdel, schemacnt,sysstat2,sysstat3, crdate,expdate,deltrig,instrig,ckfirst,cache, objspare,versionts,loginame,identburnmax,spacestate,erlchgts,lobcomp_lvl
from sysobjects o where type = 'U'
```

Any other idea on how to know whether the table has been updated?

Comment: Are you interested in determining whether a table has _ever_ been update, or whether it has been updated at a certain _time_?  If the latter, then one design change you could make would be to add a column for the last updated time to your table.

Comment: The latter, and that what I suspected. Just want to make sure is there any other possible way.

Comment: Even if there is another way, it might by Sybase-specific, which would mean that if you ever were to port to or support another database it might not work there.

Comment: sybase spesific is an ok solution for this case. I prefer put the updated date + trigger though, but thats not my call to make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way using [datachange](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36271.1570/html/blocks/blocks116.htm) function.

```
select convert(varchar(30),o.name) AS table_name,
row_count(db_id(), o.id) AS row_count,
datachange('AAA_TABLE', null, null) AS changes
from sysobjects o
where type = 'U' and o.name='AAA_TABLE'
order by table_name
```

Before updating the table result was :
    [image]

After updating with below SQL :

```
update AAA_TABLE set TYPE='1234' where ID=1 //previously TYPE was 1233
```

Result changed to :

[image]

Field "changes" was updated with new value, seems this is an ok solution, but  I am still open with any other idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you database admin set up the systabstats update daily, you can use the following query to get the last modified/updated date of a table.

```
select MAX(statmoddate) as last_modified_date
from systabstats
where id = object_id('table_name')
```